# How to create contract in geth private blockchain network?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I am able to publish my contract in testrpc , but when i am trying to publish same contract in geth, i am getting below error:

creation of lease errored: `Gas required exceeds limit: 3000000`. An important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable function (that's also the reason of strong gas estimation).

Though I have 26000 ether in my account.
Any suggestion what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Now it's got resolved just changed the chainid to 15

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to provide more gas to your contract deployment. The error is explicit:

> Gas required exceeds limit: 3000000.

Just proovide more gas. Moreover, I would recommend you to check your contract again, check gas requirement with remix, and optimize it. More than 3m gas is quite big already.